# How Can I Put Meta_Compare in the Database-Query?

Tags: database, query, wpdb

Yes, I know that this can easily be done with built in wp_query but I need this in Wpdb query. I have a custom field and I need to display posts where this field does not exist. By the way can I get the same results with a normal wp_query? The code is below:

```
 $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
 "SELECT ID, post_title, post_name FROM wp_posts
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
 INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
 INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =      wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
 WHERE
 wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 1
 AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'my_meta_key'
 AND META_COMPARE = 'NOT EXISTS'
 AND post_type = 'post'
 AND post_status = 'publish' 
 AND post_title LIKE %s ORDER BY post_title ASC",
 $letter . '%'
 ));
```

Comment: There is no `META_COMPARE` column in any of the Core tables that I have ever seen. Your question and your code are unclear and if you are going to roll your own SQL, you need to learn the Core database structure inside out.

Comment: Yes, I know there is no 'META_COMPARE' column and it's just a sample. I need a similar comparison method. My code is above and I need to find a way to display posts where a certain meta_key doesn't exists.

Comment: This is the ordinary wp_query version of what I want with wpdb.
`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'my_meta_key', 'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' ) );`